# Magento2 : How to override any product custom option price sorting in list page

Tags: magento2, custom-options, product-list, sorting

I have one simple product it's price zero(0). it has a custom option with name and price like:

```
-------------------------
   Name           Price
-------------------------
 product A         10

 product B         00

 product C         30

 product D         20
```

by default price sort is working like 0,10,20,30. But i want to sort start from 10,20,30 while any custom product has 0 price.

Please check image.
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This can be done using **Plugin**

Create the following files in your module: (Assuming you have your own module registered already)

> Create your **Plugin** under ***Vendor/Modulename/etc/di.xml***
>
> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Modulename::addCustomOptions" type="Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Model\Config" />
</type>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin name="Vendor::addPriceDescendingFilterInToolbar" type="Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
</type>
```

> Then create a **config.php** under namespace ***Vendor/Modulename/Plugin/Model/Config.php***

and put this code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Config  {


protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}


public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
{
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    $currencySymbol = $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();

    // Remove specific default sorting options
    $default_options = [];
    $default_options['name'] = $options['name'];

    //New sorting options
    $customOption['price_pcs'] = __( ' Price customSorting' );

    //Merge default sorting options with custom options
    $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);

    return $options;
}
}
```

> Then override the Toolbar.php ***Vendor/Modulename/Plugin/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

use this code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{

public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $collection
) {
    $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
    $result = $proceed($collection);

    if ($currentOrder) {
        if ($currentOrder == 'price_pcs') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('(price = 0, price)', 'asc');
        }
    }


    return $result;
}
}
```

Comment: This uploaded module is working like default module working for sorting price. please check my update quetions with image. thanks for reply.

Comment: @Sarfaraj , clarification , so you want highest to lowest? what's with the two custom option and simple product?

Comment: i want lowest to highest if custom option price is lower than product price then it should display first. like that

Comment: from your illustration, it would be 1 2 3 4?

Comment: i think you need custom option price first if its is lower than higher which is minimum than other product price.

Comment: I see, you want a custom input for your custom sort options?

Comment: @magefms Absolutely  Right

Comment: yes i want to sort custom option price also which is greater than 0 then it should be sort with all product like default sorting work.